# Issues with importing resource to terraform module

Tags: terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm, terraform-modules

I have created module named **workflow** for Azure LogicApp
Here is the module:

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "LogicApp" {
    name                             = "${var.LogicAppName}"
    location                         = "${var.LogicAppLocation}"
    resource_group_name = "${var.rgName}"
    workflow_schema         = "${var.schema}"
}
```

In `workflow_schema` i'm specifying the path to my file which contains the logicapp configuration

In main `config.tf` I have the following setup:

```
module "workflow" {
  source                     = "./modules/workflow/"
  LogicAppName       = "LaName"
  LogicAppLocation  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  rgName                   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  schema                   = "${file("./path/to/the/file/LaName")}"
}
```

So, when I'm running `terraform init` and `terraform plan` everything works perfectly fine.

Since my logic app was created earlier, I want to import it so that terraform apply won't overwrite it.

I am running the following command and it returns the error:

```
terraform import module.workflow.azurerm_logic_app_workflow.LogicApp /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myRgName/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/LaName

Error: Import to non-existent module

module.workflow is not defined in the configuration. Please add configuration
for this module before importing into it.
```

I'm using the following versions of software:

```
Terraform v0.12.13
+ provider.azurerm v1.28.0
```

If anyone has any ideas why `terraform import` fails, please share them.

Comment: You named your module `LaName`. Fix the typo and you should be fine.

Comment: @MattSchuchard yep, i've made typo here.
updated the post

Comment: Hi @Yarko.Z, may I know if your issue was solved ?

Comment: Hi @HuryShen, no unfortunately it wasn't. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I see the issue in naming.
Your module is named `workflow` and in your configuration you name the resource `workflow` too, this should be different. You are trying to import into the resource directly.
Example:

```
module "workflow-azure" {
  source                   = "./modules/workflow/"
  LogicAppName             = "LaName"
  LogicAppLocation         = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  rgName                   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  schema                   = "${file("./path/to/the/file/LaName")}"
}
```

and the import should be then

```
terraform import module.workflow-azure.azurerm_logic_app_workflow.LogicApp /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myRgName/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/LaName
```